# When mounting, what does -t mean?

Tags: mount, vmware

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine (VMWare) running on a windows machine. To gain access to a shared folder I run....

```
 sudo mount -t vboxname sharedfolder /location/of/share
```

What does the -t do in this command?

I've searched around and [read docs](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html) but cannot seem to find any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -t vfstype
              The  argument  following the -t is used to indicate the file system type.
```

> The filesystem types which are currently supported include: adfs,
>   affs, autofs, cifs, coda, coherent, cramfs, debugfs, devpts, efs, ext,
>   ext2, ext3, ext4, hfs, hfsplus, hpfs, iso9660, jfs, minix, msdos,
>   ncpfs, nfs, nfs4, ntfs, proc, qnx4, ramfs, reiserfs, romfs, squashfs,
>   smbfs, sysv, tmpfs, ubifs, udf, ufs, umsdos, usbfs, vfat, xenix, xfs,
>   xiafs. Note that coherent, sysv and xenix are equivalent and that
>   xenix and coherent will be removed at some point in the future - use
>   sysv instead. Since kernel version 2.1.21 the types ext and xiafs do
>   not exist anymore. Earlier, usbfs was known as usbdevfs. Note, the
>   real list of all supported filesystems depends on your kernel.<sup>[Mount Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)</sup>